# Installation hangs on partitioning step on 15.04 x64

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 15.04

As titled, I tried to install today the 15.04 x64 but it hangs at the partitioning step.

I have a partition for window and one for ubuntu, I already formatted the ubuntu one so now I am stuck because there is no grub that can boot even windows.

It hangs after I select the ubuntu partition, select the ext4, format flag, point `/`, then I confirm my changes and then it hangs

I tried to wait something like one hour, nothing..

I tried also to not select the update and the third part software in the previous step (I read it helped in some cases) but no success.

I also noticed I can access the linux partition at the begin, before starting on "installing ubuntu" from the live desktop. Then when it hangs and I quit, I cant access it any more, it complains about some D-BUS..

I already tried AHCI and IDE mode, no success

I also tried to boot with all the "Other Options" on (noacpi, etc..) except "Only free softare", no success

What can I do?

Ps: I noticed the ubuntu partition get mounted and unmounted continuously..

Comment: I had this problem and I went to check the console (Ctrl+Alt+1) and there were many errors on /dev/sda... it was an old, inactive computer, and I believe the controller might have deteriorated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have good and bad news..

The good news is that I solved, the bad one is that I don't know how I did..

I will write down what I remember in order to be as much useful as I can.

I burnt also a dvd to see if the problem was my usb pen, but it turned out also the dvd had the same problem.

So I booted again with my usb. Until that, I always created and choose the partitions where install ubuntu manually. I thought to give a try with some automatic procedural.

I have a 256GB ssd so partitioned, 100GB to win, 1GB swap and the rest to a ext4 partition. 
I already had installed win8.1 on one single partition (no system reserved small partition). So I imagined I could install Ubuntu on the ext4 partition by choosing "install ubuntu along windows", but I was wrong, once I clicked this, I had the choise to distribute my space outside win partition to two additional partitions, one for data (photo, documents, music, video, etc) and another for ubuntu itself.

So I clicked back, I chose the second one, "format the whole hd and install only ubuntu" but just for playing with the menu and check out if there were other options, I didn't go further than the confirmation menu and then I went back.

I tried once again the "manual choise", I set up my ex4 partition by selecting the format option and the `/` mount point, then I confirmed and then when the bottoms went grey, I tried to play a little with the keyboard, especially pressing randomly the arrows keys.

It accessed the following menu, I couldn't believe that..

Anyway, if this last time would have failed too, I was going to install it on the ssd through one of my laptop as last chance before downgrading to 14.10 and then upgrade.

I am sorry I can't give a rational explanation to this, but it worked, I wish anyone with my same problem to solve it too, good luck with that!

Answer (score 1):

Had the some problem.

My solution was to Try Ubuntu, then open GParted Partition Editor, **format the previous Ubuntu partition** and then install worked fine!